# Null Pointer Exception Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make a button, count clicks and display them in a text view.
Tried everything i knew.
XML:

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gpulay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/master_control_text_gpulay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Master Control :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus_gpulay"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Fragment { 

    int c=0;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ListView GPU_LAYOUT = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.gpu, container, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) GPU_LAYOUT.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Button plus = (Button) GPU_LAYOUT.findViewById(R.id.butt1);

        plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     //null pointer this line, but it's from .srtText i think
            public void onClick(View v) {
                c++;
                text.setText(c);
            }
        });

    }

    return GPU_LAYOUT;
}
```

App force closes when i open it, so i don't even see the main layout.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code neatly when posting so its easy for people to read.

Comment: Check that `Button plus =(Button) GPU_LAY.findViewById(R.id.butt1);` is actually putting something in plus, `findViewById` can return `null`.

Comment: I have posted it using my phone, i am sorry.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and step over it using F6, then check if it is null by hovering on GPU_LAYOUT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NPE` is coming from here

```
text.setText(c);
```

you are using the wrong `setText()` method. When you place an `int` in there it looks for a `resource` with that `id`. You need to give it a `String`. You can do this several ways. One way is to change it to

```
text.setText("" + c);
```

You could also do

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(c));
```

[TextView Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) notice the different methods.

Comment: Both methods are basicly doing the same thing, but "" + c is way shorter, so i would prefer that method.

Comment: Yep, I just wanted to give a couple options. I usually use the second method just because I think its more explicit when looking at it.

Comment: It works!Thanks! .setText(""+c); didn't work, but the second method worked.Thank you!

Comment: @user2797132 You're welcome. Please accept as the correct answer by clicking the check mark next to it...its the SO way :)

Comment: Sorry, i am new here.Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, I saw that which is why I mentioned it. You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Its just wrong to create your app in onCreateView while working in an Activity.

You can still do all this in your onCreate Method.

My Guess would be that GPU_Layout is null or doesnt contain your button. Thats why button (plus) is Null and calling setOnClickListener on it throws a NullPointerException.

Also it would help if you could explain WHEN the error Occurs, during inflating/building the Activity or during actually pressing the Button

Comment: I agree. You should be using onCreate, onCreateView is for Fragments, not Activities.

Comment: App doesn't even start.It force closes.

Comment: so the problem is that you are not referencing your button properly. post your onCreateCode and corresponding layout as well

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to extend your class from Fragment instead of Activity. Then your method `onCreateView` will work. Then set this fragment as contentView of your Activity.

2) You can't set int as text of textView or any other widget. You need to convert it into String first using `String.valueOf(count);`